Data Explorer still using old (now broken) icon link
Just reporting a small bug.  Data Explorer's icon has not (yet) been updated:

Its icon is no longer
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cogsci/img/apple-touch-icon.png

but is now
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/psychology/img/apple-touch-icon.png


MSE report with a proposed quick fix: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332277/158100 but that table gets updated from a different source so at best if fixes the issues temporarily

Why not simply use "https://[site].stackexchange.com/favicon.ico" for all SE sites? Then everything will automatically stay in synch. Any change of logo will need to be made in only one place.

It looks like this issue ended up being fixed at some point; I see the "PN" icon on the SEDE homepage now. Safe to mark this as [status-completed]?

@V2Blast: looks completed to me.

Given the Planned Maintenance scheduled for Wednesday, February 5, 2020 for Data Explorer, I took the opportunity to raise this problem on meta.SE.  This was the reply:

I am aware of the request to fix that issue but it’s not as easy as it first appears. That fix is out of scope for this maintenance window. I’ll circle back to it after we’re done and see if we can resolve it. – Taryn♦


This seems to be a long-standing issue affecting several other sites as well.
A developer answered another related question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293145/401068 but so far there seems to be no resolution. I suspect it's a rather low-priority issue given the data explorer is a bit of a niche tool.
